# C# не видит расширение IServiceCollection.Configure<>()

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ddd

Недавно начал изучать DDD и из того, что уже узнал, попытался написать телеграм-бота с использованием NuGet-пакета `Telegram.Bot`, при этом делая структуру проекта. И сейчас моя задача состоит в том, чтобы перенести секцию `BotSettings` из `appsettings.json` в класс C#. На данный момент мне нужен только уникальный токен бота

`appsettings.json`:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    ...
  }, 
  ...,
  "BotSettings":
  {
    "Token": "*В этой строке находится токен бота*"
  }
}
```

И на данный момент мой POCO-класс выглядит таким образом:

```cs
namespace TelegramBot.Domain.POCOs;

public class BotConfiguration
{
    public string? Token { get; init; }
}
```

И в этом же пространстве имён, я создал ещё один **статический** класс `Configuration` для методов расширения `IServiceCollection`, который выглядит следующим образом:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace TelegramBot.Domain.POCOs;

public static class Configuration
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddTOptions(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
    {
        IConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection("Bot");
        if (section.Value == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("Services.AddTOptions: there no \"Bot\" section in appsettings.json");
        }
        services.Configure<BotConfiguration>(config.GetSection("Bot"));
        return services;
    }
}
```

Но неожиданно, прекомпиляция сообщила о том, что он не знает метода Configure<>(). Пытался найти в интернете причину и решения, но не нашел нужного. Использовав один из вариантов (это с помощью привязки `.Bind()` и добавления POCO-класса как сервис `.AddSingleton() | .AddScope() | .AddTransient()`).

Зайдя в самый главный файл проекта `program.cs`, я заметил, что он как раз и знает о `Configure()` и `Bind()`.

`program.cs`:

```cs
using Telegram.Bot.Polling;
using TelegramBot.Application.Services;
using TelegramBot.Domain.Interfaces;
using TelegramBot.Service;
using TelegramBot.Domain.POCOs;

IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((hostCtx, services) =>
    {
        // services.AddTOptions(hostCtx.Configuration);
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();

        services.Configure<BotConfiguration>(hostCtx.Configuration.GetSection("Bot")); // без проблем
        services.AddSingleton<IUpdateHandler, UpdateHandler>();
        services.AddSingleton<IBot, Bot>();
        services.AddSingleton<IStoppingToken, StoppingToken>();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

Помогите пожалуйста, как можно исправить то, что `Configuration` не видит этих двоих методов расширения, даже при том, что я использовал юзниги, в которых хранятся эти методы расширения? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `И в этом же пространстве имён, я создал ещё один статический класс` - похоже на то, что это отдельный проект, который не имеет нужных библиотек. Метод `Configure()` находится в пакете `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions` (NuGet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Как сказал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1538646/c-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-iservicecollection-configure#comment2766686_1538646) [@EvgeniyZ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/220553/evgeniyz), в моём проекте, в котором находился тот самый статичный файл, как раз отсутствовал пакет с методами расширения. Для добавления Options в Dependency Injection, надо установить пакет из NuGet `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions`. Теперь всё работает как надо.

Евгений, огромное спасибо за участие в решение моей проблемы!